# How to install PEAR packages on Acquia Dev Desktop 2

Tags: 7, acquia-dev-desktop

I'm on Windows 7 and I would like to install PHP Code Sniffer on Acquia Dev Desktop.

I've set PATH to Dev Desktop's php executable so I can run `php` command from Command prompt.

I see pear command is not recognized. Is PEAR not installed on Acquia Dev Desktop? Or It's installed but I can't see it where?

What I want to achive is, install PHP Code Sniffer so Coder module is able to detect it.

Comment: There is a bit in 'Deploying a PEAR library' in the Acquia help files . https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/configure/non-drupal-code I hope this helps

Comment: I think that link is about Acquia Cloud. Acquia hosting service. And my question is about the dev desktop. It lead me to try install php cs using composer global, but Coder module still cannot found PHP CS

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug or insufficient documentation, and should be reported to acquia.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pear is not installed on Acquia Dev Desktop. Install it manually:

- download `go-pear.phar`
- put in C:\Users[my-account]\
- from commandline, run `php go-pear.phar` (php.exe is set to Dev Desktop's)
- press enter when prompt appear
- install PHP Code Sniffer using pear

However, coder still showing error PHP/CodeSniffer.php is not found. But I use CodeSniffer from NetBeans IDE